# RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for ResNet:

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, resnet

I am loading my model using the following code.

```
def load_model(checkpoint_path):
  '''
  Function that loads a checkpoint and rebuilds the model
  '''

  checkpoint = torch.load(checkpoint_path, map_location = 'cpu')

  if checkpoint['architecture'] == 'resnet18':
    model = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)

  # Freezing the parameters
    for param in model.parameters():
        param.requires_grad = False


  else:
    print('Wrong Architecture!')
    return None

  model.class_to_idx = checkpoint['class_to_idx']

  classifier = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
                            ('fc1', nn.Linear(512, 1024)),
                            ('relu1', nn.ReLU()),
                            ('dropout', nn.Dropout(0.2)),
                            ('fc2', nn.Linear(1024, 102))
                            ]))


  model.fc = classifier

  model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])

  return model
```

And while running

```
# Load your model to this variable
model = load_model('checkpoint.pt')
```

I get the following error,

> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>        in ()
>             1 # Load your model to this variable
>       ----> 2 model = load_model('checkpoint.pt')
>             3 
>             4 # If you used something other than 224x224 cropped images, set the 
>       correct size here
>             5 image_size = 224
>
> ```
> <ipython-input-11-81aef50793cb> in load_model(checkpoint_path)
>      30   model.fc = classifier
>      31 
> ---> 32   model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
>      33 
>      34   return model
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in 
> load_state_dict(self, state_dict, strict)
>     719         if len(error_msgs) > 0:
>     720             raise RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for 
> {}:\n\t{}'.format(
> --> 721                                self.__class__.__name__, 
> "\n\t".join(error_msgs)))
>     722 
>     723     def parameters(self):
>
> RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for ResNet:
>   Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "bn1.num_batches_tracked", 
> "layer1.0.bn1.num_batches_tracked", "layer1.0.bn2.num_batches_tracked", 
> "layer1.1.bn1.num_batches_tracked", "layer1.1.bn2.num_batches_tracked", 
> "layer2.0.bn1.num_batches_tracked", "layer2.0.bn2.num_batches_tracked", 
> "layer2.0.downsample.1.num_batches_tracked", 
> "layer2.1.bn1.num_batches_tracked", "layer2.1.bn2.num_batches_tracked", 
> "layer3.0.bn1.num_batches_tracked", "layer3.0.bn2.num_batches_tracked", 
> "layer3.0.downsample.1.num_batches_tracked", 
> "layer3.1.bn1.num_batches_tracked", "layer3.1.bn2.num_batches_tracked", 
> "layer4.0.bn1.num_batches_tracked", "layer4.0.bn2.num_batches_tracked", 
> "layer4.0.downsample.1.num_batches_tracked", 
> "layer4.1.bn1.num_batches_tracked", "layer4.1.bn2.num_batches_tracked".
> ```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I was using Pytorch 0.4.1 but Jupyter Notebook which I loaded uses 0.4.0. So I added **strict=False** attribute to **load_state_dict()**.

```
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'], strict=False)
```